# I wrote this block of code but small change making a bit difference and creates an error

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I wrote

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset=pd.read_csv("Salary_Data.csv")
X=  dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values  
y= dataset.iloc[:,1].values     

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test= train_test_split(X, y, test_size=1/3, 
random_state=0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor=LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

as I change 5th line of code to-

```
X=  dataset.iloc[:,0].values
```

(Since my dataset has only two columns age and salary)
It generates and error

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 20]
```

Comment: Can you provide a short sample of `Salary_Data.csv`?

Comment: @Nuageux ....                                                                YearsExperience Salary
1.1 39343
1.3 46205
1.5 37731
2 43525

Answer (score 3):

If you pass pandas indexing operators a list, the output remains a DataFrame. DataFrames are two dimensional which will give the values array dimensions of (n,1) where n is the number of rows. sklearn expects two dimensional data for the X array.

```
dataset.iloc[:,[0]].values
```

Answer (score 1):

The function need the array to be a shape like `(nb_row, nb_cols)`. When you use slicing (i.e. `:`), the output is a DataFrame, thus producing an array of a shape `(20,1)` in your case but if you use a single index it will return a Series which shape is `(20,)`. Use reshape to get a `(20,1)` array instead of a `(20,)`array :

```
X = dataset.iloc[:,0].values.reshape((len(dataset),1))
```